# Cannot convert string to int, must be simple but i m missing somewhere

Tags: c#, asp.net

here, i want to check only if the column Active is Yes, then get into the if loop. But it gives me an error "Cannot convert from string to int" for the last condition in if. What do you guys i can do. Thanks!!

```
if (ds != null && ds.Tables != null 
     && ds.Tables.Count > 0 
     && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 
     && ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName["Status"] == "Y")
        {
            disableloc.DataSource = ds;
            disableloc.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ds = null;
            disableloc.DataSource = ds;
            disableloc.DataBind();
```

The stored procedure is SELECT ML.locationname, 
  rtrim(ML.address) + (CASE WHEN ML.Address2 IS NOT NULL THEN ('' '' + rtrim(ML.Address2)) ELSE '''' END) + '' - ''+ ML.city + '', ''+ ML.state as address,
  ML.locationid,
  ML.merchantid, 
  case when ML.active <> ''Y'' then ''Deactive'' else ''Active'' end [Status], 
  (SELECT count(*) as retval 
   FROM merchant_statistics 
   WHERE type = ''merchant'' 
    AND locationID= ML.LocationID 
    AND status = ''clicked'') as stat, 
'' '' as button,'' '' as blank ,

   dbo.GetCouponCountForLocations(@_merchantid,ML.locationID) couponCount,
   MP.DomainName,
   (SELECT Count(*) FROM Promotion WHERE LocationId = ML.locationid AND PostType = 1) AS jobs
 FROM merchant_location ML , Merchant_Pages MP
 WHERE MP.LocationID = ML.LocationID
 AND   ML.merchantid  = @_merchantid  Order By '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compilation error is caused because `ColumnName` returns a String, and the only indexer String defines is an integer indexer that returns the character at the specified position.

Assuming you are trying to access the value of the "Active" column for the first row:

`ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName["Active"] == "Y"`

should be

`ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Active"] == "Y"`

Answer (score 2):

ColumnName actually return the name of the data column, in your case , ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName return the name of the first column. It's a string, so you can get one of the chars in the string using [] operator. 
But you have to pass an int, instead of string "Active", so you get the error.
I guess you mean to check the column value instead. In the case, you have to use

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Active"]== "Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at `ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName["Active"]`

You are trying to specify the column twice, one time too many.

Replace it with
    `ds.Tables[0].Columns[0] == "Y"`
or  `ds.Tables[0].Columns["Active"] == "Y"`

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName["Active"] returns an int and not a string.

Edit:
While my answer was technically correct (the returned value was an int), it was not the desired answer.  My apologies.  As other posters have mentioned, you need to get the value from the row, not the column.

Comment: Isn't `ColumnName` a property of `Columns[0]`?

Comment: The stored procedure from where it gets ds values is edited in the question . Please go through it and let me know.

Comment: @Winston Smith, very good point.  Reading the question closely is always the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

`ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName[should be an INT here]`

This returns a character at that passed in index of that column FYI.

Comment: @snow: The indexer is overloaded, it can take an int or a string or a DataColumn, IIRC. So it's not should, but could  :)

Comment: @leppie I don't think it has any overloads for 'ColumnName' property, only can pass in an index!  At least in my editor that's what it shows

Comment: @leppie: Wrong indexer, see top answers. Snow is right (but does not give a solution).

Comment: Oh deary me! I missed that completely!  2 steps back. I was thinking about the Columns property...  Weekend now :)